# Go Transitive or Intransitive

Tags: transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

I'm a little confused by the verb 'go'. I know that it is intransitive. My issue is that I intuitively feel that it may have some transitive uses when used in the context of activities. For example:

> Let's go fishing.

It follows the template 'subject verb object' so I would assume that in this context "go" is transitive.

Can someone please explain to me why my intuition is wrong?

Comment: "Fishing" seems to me to express more purpose than a direct object. "Let's go in order to do what?"

Comment: As in _We went fishing_; _let_ is not necessary for the construction. These are often called "serial verbs" and occur more frequently in other languages, where a sentence might go something like "He went cut split stacked the wood". English does have some serial verb constructions with _come_ and _go_ -- _Come sit with me; Go wash the dishes_, and also concatenatives: _Come and sit with me; Go and wash the dishes_; they have past tenses (_He went and did it_), but the serials don't (*_He went washed the dishes_).

Comment: ... Collins Cobuild calls these 'phase structures' where the 'action' (used very imprecisely) is described only by the two verbs together. 'He **went singing** with the choir last Thursday' (contrast 'He went, singing'). 'Let's **go shopping**. 'She **sat knitting**.  The 'go fishing' group. They're analogues of auxiliary constructions (she **was knitting**) but the leading verbs have semantic content.

Comment: When we say, go hunting, go shipping etc., aren't they ( the ing-verbs) used as adverbials?

Comment: @RamPillai No: they are catenative complement clauses functioning as complement of "go". See my answer.

Comment: @BillJ, Agree with you.  I asked this doubt because I remember having seen somewhere in ELU a similar example referred to as adverbials.  :)

Answer (score 4):

> *Let's go fishing.*

Yes, "go" is intransitive here, and "fishing" is a verb, not a noun.

It's essentially a catenative construction.

1st person inclusive *let*-imperatives contain the catenative verb *let* together with an NP object (here "us" reduced to '*s*) and a bare infinitival clause (here *go fishing*) as second complement.

In your particular example, the catenative verb *go* has the gerund-participial clause "fishing" as its catenative complement.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I will need to read into gerund-participial clauses.

Answer (score -1):

Let's go . In this sentence 'fishing' works as an adverb. An adverb cannot be the object. So the verb '' is an  verb.

I like swimming. In this sentence 'swimming' is a gerund. It functions as a noun. It is the object. So 'like' is a transitive verb. (A gerund can be the subject or the object.)

gerund= verb + ing

present participle= verb + ing

Comment: *Fishing* is not an adverb!!!

Comment: so noun? or adjective?

Comment: ... It's a verb!

Comment: It is a present participle (verb + ing) It cannot be the object. But a gerund (verb + ing) can be the object.

Comment: 'We went fishing' and 'we sat fishing' use a phase structure perhaps best seen as an analogue of the auxiliary construction 'We were fishing'.

Comment: If you believe in the difference between participles and gerunds in English, then it would be a participle. You're correct, it's not an object. It' a catenative complement. (See Bill's answer above).